# Fluent UI - Detail List Context Menu Props update based on the local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have fluent UI detail list context menu. when I right click it visible and context menu inside have list of checkbox update the check box based on the local state not working.
Here is the codepen example which i tried : https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/EpJaEq?editors=0110

```
<DetailList
    setKey="items"
    items={selectedPivotData}
    columns={columns}
    onSelectionChanged={onSelection}
    ref={ref}
    isMultiSelection={isMultiSelection}
    onItemContextMenu={onItemContextMenu} // here is the context menu
  />
 
<ContextualMenu
      {...contextualMenu?.contextualMenuProps} //  I need to update the props based on the state changes
      className="contextMenuInList"
    />
```